# SQL Plus 12c Error on executing lines

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm new in programming on oracle databases. I installed Oracle 12c, i run sqplus, i'm connecting with test account, but when i execute some lines, such as creating a simple table and inserting rows, after few of them i'm getting: Error 45 initializing SQL Plus. Internal error.

Any advices? i searched on google but this problem is generated only when people try to load scripts, in my case i'm trying to do simple execute commands.

Comment: Can you post the statement that causes the error?

Comment: Well, i simply create a table, and then i execute some select statements, they are working fine, but then i repeat same statement for 5 times on the same table my sqplus closes with error mentioned above.

Comment: We'll probably need the *exact* commands in order to reproduce and troubleshoot.

Comment: Ok, i'm creating a new table like this: create table myrelation
(mykey char(4), name char(30), address char(50));

insert into myrelation values
('1020', 'John Smit', '1 Main Street');

insert into myrelation values
('1030', 'Linda Jade', '1 Main Street');

At the insert command the sqlplus prompt drops me with the error, after i created the table. First insert worked but second already droped me

Comment: Does it only happen with that command, or does it error out on any `create table` statement?

Comment: it happens on all statements, even if i input an incorrect statements, it allows me to execute few commands and then crashes. I suppose it's something wrong with sqlplus prompter, maybe it allows me somehow to introduce a limited number of statements.